# Genymotion is not working with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for androdid studio

Tags: android-studio, virtual-machine, virtualbox, genymotion, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed virtual box 6.1 in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for use in android studio.
Then I installed geny motion 3.1.0 but not working properly.
The error message is shown below.

I cannot degrade virtual box version as it is not suitable for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
Please suggest a solution
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with VirtualBox on Linux. You should try to recompile VirtualBox kernel module. See [this article](https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002706677--An-error-has-occurred-while-trying-to-create-a-virtualbox-host-only-network-interface-Linux-).